# Is it possible to reinit a cabal sandbox?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I find myself running the following commands often to "reinit" a sandbox to a clean state.

```
cabal sandbox delete
cabal sandbox init
cabal sandbox add-source Foo
cabal sandbox add-source Bar
cabal sandbox add-source Baz
```

Is there a way to make the sandbox "remember" the `add-sources` entries? Or is my approach just flawed? I most often run these commands because of "cabal hell" that is if cabal complains about misconfigured packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete everything except `add-source-timestamps` and `packages/` in `.cabal-sandbox`.

Comment: Followed up by the usual `cabal install --only-dependencies` this seems to work. Thank you :)